# Need help about jquery , I want to get list input has name List[index]

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get list input has name : `Person[0].ID, Person[0].Name,Person[1].ID,   Person[1].Name` same as:

```
<input name="Person[0].ID" value= "0" />
<input name="Person[0].Name" value= "Doe" />
<input name="Person[1].ID" value= "1" />
<input name="Person[1].Name" value= "Smith" />
```

and parse json :

```
 {"Person":[{"ID":"0", "Name":"Doe"}, {"ID":"1", "Name":"Smith"}]}
```

When I submit form, I receive list of Person,I want parse json to post ajax.

Comment: I completely got confuse what is your problem, do you want selectors for  `Person[0].ID, Person[0].Name,Person[1].ID,   Person[1].Name` or something else?

Comment: <input name="Person[0].ID" value= "0" />
<input name="Person[0].Name" value= "Doe" />
<input name="Person[1].ID" value= "1" />
<input name="Person[0].Name" value= "Smith" /> I want selectors all input name Person[index] and parse Json

Comment: Sorry but I fist use StackOverflow and my English skill not good

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that generates the JSON in the particular format that you want, and then use it for AJAX (or whatever). It could be something like this:

```
function generateJsonForPeople() {

    var json = {};
    json.Person = [];
    var x = 0;
    while ($('[name="Person[' + x + '].ID"]').length) {
        json.Person[x] = {};
        json.Person[x].ID  = $('[name="Person[' + x + '].ID"]').val();
        json.Person[x].Name = $('[name="Person[' + x + '].Name"]').val();
        x++;
    }

    return json;
}
```

You can see it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sat8u0y0/).

Comment: This function assumes that the index starts at 0 (if the first one is Person[1] it will return empty array), and that it is continuous (if you have Person[0], Person[1], Person[3], it will only return 0 and 1)

Comment: Thanks, i use knockout to add dynamic list of input by view model, Person[index] , index sure equals  0,1,..n. I forgot try:var jsonData = ko.toJSON(viewModel), thanks for your help!!

Comment: Thanks, but i can't votes, i am a new user!

Comment: So did it work? or you wanted a solution using knockout.js?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `serializeArray()`. It won't give you that exact structure but it'll give you a `Person` array on the resource you're sending it to.

I'd try:

```
$.post(url, $('#your-form').serializeArray());
```

and in the resource you're sending it to do a dump to see what the data looks like and make it into th format you actually need, if you do in fact need to. You can view the dump in the network panel (or just don't do the $.post at all and have the form go to the url naturally.

Comment: But I want get a part of  input from form to post ajax same my problem, can you suggest me any ways, thanks!

Comment: You can target specific elements instead of your entire form if you just want to send portions of it.

Comment: But I create dynamic list of input, user can add input follow rules: name = Person[index++].ID, and I want to parse this to json, thanks

Comment: It would still work. You'll get the array on the server the same way you would through a regular submit using `serializeArray()`.

Comment: My form has more complex input text,checkbox,textarea, I want to get a list of input have same rule attribute name : name='Person[index].ID',name='Person[index].Name',index = 0,1,...n not get other input name='somname' and parse JSON. I will try serializeArray(), any ways better than, thanks!

Comment: You can do `$('input[name^=Person]').serializeArray()`. if you just want to send that data.

Comment: I see this link, but not parse exactly what i want, http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/ ,if i try this, i will give [{name=Person[0].ID,value="0"},{name=Person[1].ID,value="1"}, i want {"Person":[{"ID":"0", "Name":"Doe"}, {"ID":"1", "Name":"Smith"}]}

Comment: I was suggesting doing this on the server side since that's exactly how your data would arrive on the server. I made up a little demo to get this client side if you needed to: http://jsbin.com/pusucuseyopo/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is my grid:

```
<table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="headRow headColumn" >STT</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn" >Mã Ngành</th>
            <th class="headRow headColumn" colspan="7">Ngành nghề</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: gifts' id="viewModel">
        <tr >

            <td class="editorTable" colspan="8">

            <input type="text" class="editorCombobox"  data-bind='value: MaNganh, attr: { name: "ListofNganh[" + $index() + "].MaNganh", id: "ThemMaNganh_"+$index() }' />
            </td>



        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="rowItemSmall" ><label data-bind='text: $index() + 1'></label> </td>
           <td class="rowItemMedium"> @Html.Label("Chi tiết:")</td>
            <td class="rowItemLarge" > <input type="text" class="editorTable"   data-bind='value: ChiTiet, attr: { name: "ListofNganh[" + $index() + "].ChiTiet" }' />

            </td>
            <td class="rowItemMedium">@Html.Label("Mã ngành CPC:") </td>
            <td class="rowItem"> 
               <input type="text" class="editorTable"   data-bind='value: MaNganhCPC, attr: { name: "ListofNganh[" + $index() + "].MaNganhCPC" }' />

            </td>
            <td class="rowItemSmall"><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeGift'>Xóa</a></td>
            <td class="rowItemSmall"><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addGift'>Thêm</a></td>
        </tr>
        @*<tr >
            <td></td>
         <td>
            <button  class="btn_blue" data-bind='click: $root.addGift'>Thêm Ngành</button>
         </td>  
        </tr>*@
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var GiftModel = function (gifts) {
    var self = this;
    self.gifts = ko.observableArray(gifts);
    self.addGift = function () {
        self.gifts.push({
            MaNganh: "",
            ChiTiet: ""
            , MaNganhCPC: ""
            , DienGiai :""
        });

    };

    self.removeGift = function (gift) {
        if (self.gifts().length > 1)
            self.gifts.remove(gift);
        else alert("Phải bắt buộc chọn 1 ngành nghề");
    };


};
var viewModel = new GiftModel(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.jsonData));

ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("viewModel"));</script>
```

Here is my Ajax post :

```
serviceURL = "/N_HOSO_TN_QUAMANG/Update_TabsChiNhanhXML";
            jdata = JSON.stringify({
                "t": {
                    "SoBNhan": $('#SoBNhan').val(),
                    "SoDKKD": $('#SoDKKD').val(),
                    "TenChiNhanh": $('#TenChiNhanh').val(),
                    "TenGiaoDichCN": $('#TenGiaoDichCN').val(),
                    "TenVietTatCN": $('#TenVietTatCN').val(),
                    "TenTiengViet_DK": $('#TenTiengViet_DK').val(),
                    "SoNha_DK": $('#SoNha_DK').val(),
                    "MsQuan_DK": $('#MsQuan_DK').val(),
                    "MsPhuong_DK": $('#MsPhuong_DK').val(),
                    "DienThoai_DK": $('#DienThoai_DK').val(),
                    "Fax_DK": $('#Fax_DK').val(),
                    "EmailDK": $('#EmailDK').val(),
                    "WebsiteDK": $('#WebsiteDK').val(),
                    "ListofNganh": ko.toJS(viewModel).gifts
                }
            });
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: jdata,
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });

    function successFunc(data, status) {
        var jdataParse = $.parseJSON(data);
        //var _SoBNhan = $('#SoBNhan').val();
        //if (_SoBNhan == '')
            $('#SoBNhan').val(jdataParse.SoBNhan);
    }


    function errorFunc() {
        //alert('error');
    }
```

Object jdata when i try parse JSON:

```
"{"t":{"SoBNhan":"2014104000057","SoDKKD":"411032000017","TenChiNhanh":"321321","TenGiaoDichCN":"321312","TenVietTatCN":"","SoNha_DK":"321321","MsQuan_DK":"D007","MsPhuong_DK":"G088","DienThoai_DK":"","Fax_DK":"","EmailDK":"","WebsiteDK":"","ListofNganh":[{"DienGiai":"dien giai 01","id":"50111","ChiTiet":"demo","MaNganh":"50111","MaNganhCPC":null,"SoBnhan":"20070123000970"},{"DienGiai":null,"id":"51200","ChiTiet":"demo02","MaNganh":"51200","MaNganhCPC":"demo","SoBnhan":"20070123000970"},{"MaNganh":"46694","ChiTiet":"321321","MaNganhCPC":"3213123","DienGiai":""}]}}"
```

And post receive  jdata what i want.
My Solution is solve, Thanks  Bill Criswell and Monty82 !!!